# Check if class exists or not in orientdb

Tags: java, orientdb

How to check if a class exists or not in orient db 
if it is not exiting in the database i need to create it and insert a record  if exists i need to insert  the record .
I need to do the same using JAVA

Answer (score 7):

You can retrieve schema information via SQL with the following statement:

```
 select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```

In particular, to retrieve a single class:

```
 select from (
    select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
 ) where name = 'YourClassName'
```

From Java:

```
 ODatabaseDocumentTx db = ...
 if(db.getMetadata().getSchema().existsClass("ClassName")){
   ...
 }
```

If you have an OrientGraph, you can get the underlying `ODatabaseDocumentTx` with

```
 graph.getRawGraph();
```

Comment: Why SQL queries you wrote is not working with uppercase?

Comment: Because the class name is stored as it is, so the = does a normal comparison. You can always do `where name.toLowerCase() = 'yourclassname'`

Comment: How about `SELECT EXPAND(CLASSES) FROM METADATA:SCHEMA`?! There is no class name here. I think in the future it should be fixed. Because in other SQL like databases the query launguage is not case sensitive.

Comment: property names (`classes` in this case) are case sensitive, this is why it doesn't work