# Do classes necessarily have to exist prior to record insertion?

Tags: orientdb

I'm coming from Neo4j and evaluating OrientDB, and I had a quick question about classes - do they have to exist prior to inserting a record?  That is, in Neo4j there's the 'MERGE' command, which will update or create a node if it doesn't exist.  Classes seem roughly equivalent to Neo4j's labels, and if a label doesn't exist when performing a MERGE, it will be created.  Is there similar functionality in OrientDB?  Currently when I try to insert a record whose class doesn't exist, OrientDB throws an exception, "Class SOME_CLASS not found in database".

I've been reading through the docs trying to get a handle on the various data models available, but I can't find anything explicit on this issue.  One thing I tried was to add a cluster, and then insert a record with a class that does not exist.  This worked, and in OrientDB Studio, under 'DB', I see the cluster with number of records equal to '1'; however, the class of that new record does not appear under 'Schema'.

If dynamic class creation of this sort isn't possible, is it acceptable to check if a class exists in the schema, and if not, create it, and then proceed with creating the record?  A different question is, if it's acceptable, is it good to do this, or should I always define the schema manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use one of the `CREATE` commands, then the object is placed in a default class; for example:

```
CREATE VERTEX
Created vertex 'V#9:0 v1' in 0.047000 sec(s).
```

(In this case, the class is `V`.)

And of course if you use the `INSERT INTO ...` form, then you have to specify a class.

So perhaps your first question boils down to whether it is possible to change the class of an OrientDB vertex or edge.

It is possible to change the parent class of a vertex -- see
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Move-Vertex.html -- but there are important caveats.

To test whether a class exists programmatically, see e.g. this SO entry:
[Check if class exists or not in orientdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497341/check-if-class-exists-or-not-in-orientdb)

This gives a Java example, but a similar approach is possible using other supported languages.

As to the wisdom of changing the class of an entity dynamically -- perhaps the safe answer is that if you can achieve whatever you want using a property label, then use labels.